# Combine two MySQL queries to one

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to combine these two queries into one query?

```
SELECT sum(amount) as credit FROM statement WHERE userId= '33003' AND debitOrCredit = '1' AND actionDate <= '2012-10-17';

SELECT sum(amount) as debit FROM statement WHERE userId= '33003' AND debitOrCredit = '0' AND actionDate <= '2012-10-17';
```

so I get the result:

```
| credit  | debit  |   
|   90    |   60   |
```

Comment: title stated `MSQL` but tagged `MySQL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html) within your SUM:

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as credit,
       sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as debit
FROM statement WHERE userId= '33003' AND actionDate <= '2012-10-17';
```

Comment: Thank you for help.

The query used in Zend Framework looks like:

$sql = $this->_dba->select()
     ->from('statement', array(
       "credit" => "sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)",
       "debit" => "sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)"))
     ->where('userId = ?', $userId)
     ->where('actionDate <= ?', $date);
     
     try
     {
      $result = $this->db->fetchRow($sql);
     }
     catch (Exception $e)
     {
      throw new Exception("Error on ....");
     }

Answer (score 2):

use `CASE` in your `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as credit,
       sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as debit
FROM   statement 
WHERE  userId= '33003'  AND 
       actionDate <= '2012-10-17';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
SELECT sum(a.amount) as credit,sum(b.amount) as debit FROM statement a left join statement b
on a.userId=b.userId
 WHERE a.userId= '33003' AND a.debitOrCredit = '1' AND b.debitOrCredit = '0' AND a.actionDate <= '2012-10-17' AND b.actionDate <= '2012-10-17' ;
```

-- Mark answered if this answer answers your question...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.
This is how I used it in Zend framework:

```
$sql = $this->_dba->select()
    ->from('statement', array(
        "credit" => "sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)",
        "debit" => "sum(CASE WHEN debitOrCredit = '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END)"))
    ->where('userId = ?', $userId)
    ->where('actionDate <= ?', $date);

    try
    {
        $result = $this->db->fetchRow($sql);
        //process result here       
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error on ...... ");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

`SELECT sum(case when debitOrCredit = '1' then amount else 0 end) as credit, sum(case when debitOrCredit = '2' then amount else 0 end) as debit FROM statement WHERE userId= '33003' AND actionDate <= '2012-10-17'`